# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined from ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: dojo, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I updated my application to 3.12 and am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

It is being triggered by the following line:

```
coordMenu.addChild(new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
    content:"<div id=\"coordsDisplay\"></div>"
}));
```

Any ideas?  It was working fine in 3.11

Comment: Is coordMenu an accordion. Looks like a timing issue. Is coordmenu created at the node specified before attempting to addChild?

Comment: In the html element are you using a lang attribute like lang="en"? When parsing using the dojo/parser then the lang="en" or similar causes a problem.

Comment: @Aamir no I saw a post on that issue and that is not the case

Comment: @Aamir I am confident it is a parse issue, as in the app not being parsed in the correct order

Comment: Did you try using the mobile parser?